# Таймер обратного отсчета для тестирования

Tags: jquery

Делаю тестирование. Время для прохождения теста получаю из базы данных в секундах. Есть проблема с таймером. Отсчёт идёт. Всё работает. Но как сделать, чтоб при постоянном обновлении страницы он не стоял на месте? Заранее спасибо.

```
function showTimer(date_t) {
var date = new Date();
date = date.getTime();

var timer = date_t - date;
if (date_t > date)
{
    var h = parseInt(timer / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24;
    if (h < 10) {
        h = '0' + h;
    }
    //Приводим результат к строке
    var i = parseInt(timer / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    //если полученное число меньше 10 прибавляем 0
    if (i < 10) {
        i = '0' + i;
    }
    //Приводим результат к строке
    var s = parseInt(timer / 1000) % 60;
    //если полученное число меньше 10 прибавляем 0
    if (s < 10) {
        s = '0' + s;
    }
    $("#timer").html(h + ":" + i + ":" + s);
    function secOut()
    {

        if (s == '00')
        {
            if (i == '00')
            {
                if (h == '00')
                {
                    alert("Время вышло");
                }
                else
                {
                    h--;
                    i = '59';
                    s = '59';
                    if (h < 10) {
                        h = '0' + h;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
                s = '59';
                if (i < 10) {
                    i = '0' + i;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            s--;
            if (s < 10) {
                s = '0' + s;
            }
        }

        $("#timer").html(h + ":" + i + ":" + s);
        localStorage["time"]=$("#timer").text();
    }
    setInterval(secOut, 1000);
}

else {
    alert("Время вышло");
}
```

}

```
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = window.location.href.split('/');
    var test_id = arr[5];
    if(localStorage.getItem("time"))
    {
        var arr=localStorage.getItem("time").split(':');
        arr[0]*=1;
        arr[1]*=1;
        arr[2]*=1;
        var time=(arr[0]*3600+arr[1]*60+arr[2])*1000;
        var date_t = new Date();
        date_t = date_t.getTime() + time;
        showTimer(date_t);
    }
    else {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/test/get_test_time",
        data: {id: test_id},
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            var data1 = data * 1000;
            var date_t = new Date();
            date_t = date_t.getTime() + data1;
            showTimer(date_t);
        }
    });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: в `local storage`  записывать время, и считывать обратно после обновления страницы.

Comment: @IlonMask в localStorage записываю же. не помогает если обновлять быстрее чем пройдет секунда